# Nhibernate Validator for Nhibernate 3.1

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

Is there a version that works with Nhibernate 3.1?  Currently I have a version that is looking for 2.1.2.4000.  Is there something I can change to be able to use the old Nhibernate Validator with the new version of Nhibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate.Validator has already been updated to NHibernate 3.1 in trunk. And the release notes also have been recently updated, so a release seems to be imminent. See the [commit log](http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Validator/?view=log).

I recommend using trunk until 1.3 is released. Also ping [Dario Quintana](http://twitter.com/darioquintana) (the maintainer), ask him if he needs any help with the release.

Answer (score 1):

See if [assembly binding redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) can help you here. If new version NHibernate contains no breaking changes regarding to NHibernate Validator, this should work.